# Ubuntu 20.04 - issue with VNC

Tags: server, gnome, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc

I have been using Ubuntu on a headless server (with Ubuntu desktop) and a vnc with Gnome since 16.04 LTS. My setup is very similar to everyone else who publishes a How To.

I plug in a monitor/keyboard/mouse and upgraded to 20.04 today and was going through my setup steps and all appeared good.  Everything working as expected.

- Using Gdm
- Using TigerVNC
- Using Gnome xorg

_

1. I create VNC server session
2. enable vncserver service
3. login (vncviewer) from the server
4. login with my remote Windows PC (Real VNC Viewer).

**However, when I logout of the Ubuntu server, the PC's Real VNC session is killed after about 7 seconds.  Logging back in via Putty or directly in the server (vncviewer -list) shows the process as stale.**

I am thinking that vncserver, and maybe other desktop services, are being suspended or killed upon logout.  I do not believe this should happen when the vncserver service is running.

My temporary workaround it to remain logged in and "lock" the screen.

**Anyone know of a way to "continue running in the background when I logout" solution?**

Thanks in advance.

```
~/.vnc/xstartup
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid blue
vncconfig -iconic &
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session &
```

( also tried this without `--exit-with-session` )

Comment: Same specs, same problem. Anyone?